# Why is the current user not being passed to my template?

Tags: django

Ok, so I am querying 'messages' and attempting to display 'request.user' messages on the right side of the page and the messages of the user who messaged the request.user on the left side of the page. However, request.user is not being passed to the template and it's displaying ALL the messages on the left side of the page. What am I doing wrong here? Also, I specified a custom user model called Profile for user.

**views.py/messages**

```
def messages(request):
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'dating_app/messages.html', {'messages': messages})
```

**messages.html**

```
<div id="msg-list-div" class="panel-body">
        <ul id="msg-list" class="list-group">

            {% for obj in messages %}
                {% if obj.user == request.user %}
                    <li class="text-right list-group-item">{{ obj.message }}</li>
                {%else%}
                    <li class="text-left list-group-item">{{ obj.message }}</li>
                {%endif%}   
            {% empty %}
                    <li class="text-right list-group-item">No messages yet...Keep mingling!</li>
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True






class InstantMessage(models.Model):

    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    message = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Are you authenticated when you access the page?  If you are not it will not be able to retrieve user details.

Comment: yes, the user is already logged in

Answer (score 0):

So, what I was doing incorrectly was simply not referring to my InstantMessanger models attribute 'sender' when I was passing 'obj.user' into my template. It should of been 'obj.sender' as I had a sender and receiver attributes to my InstantMessage model which both were foreign keys to both users. I simply had to provide the attribute, and it worked correctly.

{% for obj in messages %}
                {% if obj.sender == request.user %}
                    {{ obj.message }}
                {%else%}
                    {{ obj.message }}
                {%endif%}   
            {% empty %}
                    No messages yet...Keep mingling!
            {% endfor %}